# convert an ASN.1 object

Tags: java, asn.1

how can I convert from ASN.1 code something like that:

> HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrSystemProcesses.0 = Gauge32: 52

I want to desplay only 52
In fact,when I browse the net I found a jar file that called Sck.jar that allow you to convert from ASN.1,I put it in the project library but I don't know how can I used.

Comment: Could you provide the BER / DER encoded byte stream that you want to decode? Also, please include a URL to that JAR that you use. Did you have a chance to look at other Java BER decoders that have JavaDoc and examples?

Answer (score 0):

How you write code to display the values is specific to the particular tool you are using.  You might consider using an ASN.1 Tools which has good documentation and a good technical support department (if you choose a commercial tool).  A good list of ASN.1 Tools (free as well commercial) is available at http://www.itu.int/ITU-T/asn1/links/index.htm.  A good tool will provide a simple way to display any of the ASN.1 values.